# ExtJs-4.1 Grid locking + summary feature

Tags: extjs4.1

I am having a grid with the locking feature and the summary feature. 
If locking feature is used then summary feature doesnt work. Reading the forumns found that when locking is used the ExtJs creates two grid 1. Grid with normal view 2. Grid with locking view. Is it the possibility that the summary feature is not added in the second grid which is created when we lock the columns.

If yes then how can i achieve this ?

I thought Using ExtJs4.1 would help in resolving this issue. But yet I am unable to resolve this thing.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I'm trying to use locking + filter plugin + stateful. Regarding stateful, only sorting feature works as expected. Filter plugin doesn't work at all. Do you have any information about that?

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in the 4.1 demos for locking grid with summary feature.

See here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid/locking-group-summary-grid.html

You'll need to edit it a bit if you're not grouping, but it should work.